# ASP.NET Form Builder?

Tags: asp.net, sql, templates

I have a number of departments that need to put forms online...I'm wondering if there is a way for me to allow them to do this dynamically - rather than me programming each form? It does need to flow into a database...I'm thinking something similar to Wufoo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use a Workflow to respond to the types of input controls they select, and build both the form and DB queries dynamically?